# PyQt5 use default image icon when changing stylesheet

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm creating a custom stylesheet for a QTreeWigdet using PyQt5. Instead of loading custom images for the arrows, is there a way to use the default RightArrow/LeftArrow icons? I've tried the code below to no avail.

```
AnnotationTree = """
    QTreeWidget::branch:selected:closed {
        background: rgb(75,75,75);
        image: Qt::RightArrow;
    }
    QTreeWidget::branch:selected:open {
        background: rgb(75,75,75);
        image: Qt::DownArrow;
    }
    QTreeWidget::item:selected {
        background: rgb(75,75,75);
        color: white;
        border-left: 2px solid orange;
    }
"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a stylesheet on a complex widget (especially when using pseudo-selectors) results in completely overriding the painting of the element by ignoring the default style.

Qt doesn't provide access to primitive elements such as branches, but it's possible to use the style painting to draw pixmaps of elements, as long as their size is known to be fixed in all situations.

A possible solution is to create all required icons when starting the application (by subclassing QApplication) and saving them in the SO temp folder.

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QTreeWidget::branch:selected:closed {{
                background: rgb(75,75,75);
                image: url({iconPath}/closed.png);
            }}
            QTreeWidget::branch:selected:open {{
                background: rgb(75,75,75);
                image: url({iconPath}/open.png);
            }}
            QTreeWidget::item:selected {{
                background: rgb(255,255,255);
                color: white;
                border-left: 2px solid orange;
            }}
        """.format(iconPath=QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().iconPath))
        # ...


class Application(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    _iconsDone = True
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        tmpDir = QtCore.QDir(QtCore.QStandardPaths.writableLocation(
            QtCore.QStandardPaths.TempLocation))
        iconDirName = '__qticons'
        if not tmpDir.exists(iconDirName):
            tmpDir.mkpath(iconDirName)
        self.iconPath = tmpDir.absoluteFilePath(iconDirName)

    def setStyle(self, style):
        if isinstance(style, str):
            self.makeIcons(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create(style))
        else:
            self.makeIcons(style)
        super().setStyle(style)

    def makeIcons(self, style):
        iconSize = style.pixelMetric(style.PM_SmallIconSize) - 1
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem()
        opt.palette = style.standardPalette()
        opt.rect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, iconSize, iconSize)
        opt.state |= style.State_Enabled
        baseState = style.State(opt.state)

        iconStates = (
            ('closed', style.State_Children), 
            ('open', style.State_Children | style.State_Open), 
        )

        for iconName, state in iconStates:
            opt.state = baseState | state
            pm = QtGui.QPixmap(iconSize, iconSize)
            pm.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
            qp = QtGui.QPainter(pm)
            style.drawPrimitive(style.PE_IndicatorBranch, opt, qp)
            qp.end()
            pm.save(QtCore.QDir(self.iconPath).absoluteFilePath(
                '{}.png'.format(iconName)))

        self._iconsDone = True

    def exec(self):
        if not self._iconsDone:
            self.makeIcons(self.style())
            self._iconsDone = True
        return super().exec()

    def exec_(self):
        return self.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = Application(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

But, there's a catch: you're *completely* relying on the current style painting. In your stylesheet you're using very dark background colors, while default styles normally assume that an item view's background is very bright (white, usually). The result is that the default arrow (which is dark) might not almost invisible. For instance, this is the result on my system:

[image: almost invisible arrow]

So, as long as you're providing customized coloring, you cannot rely on the current style (which you don't know what is) to draw system primitives, and that's another reason for which Qt StyleSheets properly avoid using the standard painting as a fallback: if you want custom styling, you *must* provide everything, including the branch icon.

Comment: Wonderfully detailed response. Thanks for the information.